# Firebase app initialization fails with invalid-credential (firebase function initiatlization)

Tags: node.js, firebase

As per [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_the_sdk):

*If you are using the Node.js Admin SDK in a Cloud Function, you can automatically initialize the SDK through the functions.config() variable:*

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

But when I try this very simple piece of code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

exports.orhub = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.end()
})
```

I get the following error:

```
error: FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the \"credential\" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: \"Error fetching access token: invalid_grant (Bad Request)\". There are two likely causes: (1) your server time is not properly synced or (2) your certificate key file has been revoked. To solve (1), re-sync the time on your server. To solve (2), make sure the key ID for your key file is still present at https://console.firebase.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/project. If not, generate a new key file at https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk."}
```

My Ubuntu pc has date and timezone automatically synced, so that's not the problem. I created this project today, so I got the latest modules.

So, what's the problem? Isn't "Cloud Functions" mentioned in the docs the same as Firebase functions?

Comment: Are you running this deployed to Cloud Functions, or in the local emulator via the Firebase CLI?

Comment: in the local emulator, @DougStevenson!

Comment: Do you also have `gcloud` installed?

Comment: Not sure, Doug, I'll try later and come back to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since version `5.9.1` of `firebase-admin` it's possible to call `initializeApp` without any arguments. [See release notes here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node). I would suggest updating to the latest version.

Comment: Nor for me. But authenticating properly as per https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup?hl=en-419 did

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, and I solved it as follows:

- Go to the firebase console / Settings / Service accounts
- Click on the option of [ Generate new private key ]
- Load the file to the project
- Implementation code:

  ```
  const admin = require('firebase-admin');

  var serviceAccount = require('PATH/file_private_key.json');

  admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
      databaseURL: "https://DATA_BASE_URL.firebaseio.com"
  });
  ```

More info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start

Comment: How do you perform Bullet #3 "Load the file to the project"  with GCP console or Firebase Console ?

Answer (score 2):

**Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions upgrade guide: beta to version 1.0 or higher**
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

New initialization syntax for firebase-admin
firebase-admin is now initialized without any parameters within the Cloud Functions runtime.

**Before (<= v0.9.1)**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

**Now (>= v1.0.0)**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
```

Comment: This is not working for me... i get the following error:

Error updating user:  { Error: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token

any hints?

Answer (score 0):

in my case,
i use `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env variable to set the path to json settings file

 and in my firebase service file i write:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
});

module.exports = admin
```

To slove this bug i need to add in app.js / server.js the line:

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

That way firebase will be able to recognize and use env variables.
**all bs"d**